# Are the changes to "unclear," "too broad," and "primarily opinion-based" close votes MY-specific or SE-wide?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I just noticed that some of the close vote reasons have been slightly tweaked:

[image]

Specifically:

- "Unclear what you're asking" has been changed to "Needs details or clarity"
- "Too broad" has been changed to "Needs more focus"
- "Primarily opinion-based" has been shortened to just "Opinion-based"

The fine print below each one remains the same, as far as I can tell. Seemingly the change was to help OPs be able to target problems with their problems more effectively, particularly ones new to the site.

Was this just a MY change, or was this rolled out SE-wide as a part of their post notices update?

Comment: I'm guessing SE-wide, because I can't imagine mods here doing that without community discussion.  (Also, at least as of a couple months ago, mods couldn't edit those reasons, and if it came from SE they wouldn't have a reason to do it only here.)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/05/new-post-notices-improving-feedback-on-stack-overflow-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're networkwide.